# OTP Google Acc. Compatible

Tags: cryptography, hmacsha1, google-authenticator, one-time-password

I'm working on the implementation of a OTP Google Acc. compatible.

So far, I've been using

-RFC2104(http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt),

-RFC4226(http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4226.txt),

-RFC6238(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238), and following this schema :

[Pseudo code Time OTP] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator#Pseudocode_for_Time_OTP)

```
function GoogleAuthenticatorCode(string secret)
 key := base32decode(secret)
 message := floor(current Unix time / 30)
 hash := HMAC-SHA1(key, message)
 offset := value of last nibble of hash
 truncatedHash := hash[offset..offset+3]  //4 bytes starting at the offset
 Set the first bit of truncatedHash to zero  //remove the most significant bit 
 code := truncatedHash mod 1000000
 pad code with 0 until length of code is 6
 return code
```

Until "  hash := HMAC-SHA1(key, message)  " everything is ok. I checked multiple time the result through other HMAC-SHA1 converters. (Well, I think so).

But then, I think something must go wrong ... because obviously I'm not getting the same code as my google-authenticator app (android). (At least it's still a 6-digits value).

The part I'm not quiet sure to understand well is :

```
 offset := value of last nibble of hash
 truncatedHash := hash[offset..offset+3]  //4 bytes starting at the offset
 Set the first bit of truncatedHash to zero  //remove the most significant bit
```

Could someone give me a more detailed explanation on this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you may take the value of `offset` incorrectly.
The statement

> value of last nibble of hash

is pretty vague if you don't have a proper definition of bit and byte ordering. 
Quoted wikipedia page has links to a number of implementations, I think [this Java implementation](https://github.com/mclamp/JAuth/blob/master/JAuth/PasscodeGenerator.java) is something to check your code against:

```
byte[] hash = ...

// Dynamically truncate the hash
// OffsetBits are the low order bits of the last byte of the hash
int offset = hash[hash.length - 1] & 0xF;
```